# Symfony redirect based on tld

Tags: php, symfony

I have multiple domainnames linked to the same application. They only all redirect to the main tdl nl. Therefore I use the following config and this works fine:

```
company_core:
resource: "@CoreBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /
host:     www.mydomainname.{tld}
defaults:
   tld: nl
requirements:
   tld: "nl|eu"
```

Would it be possible that when an user opens the domain www.mydomainname.eu that it will be redirected to www.mydomainname.nl/eu instead-off www.mydomainname.nl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use Apache (or Nginx) for this kind of task:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect to cannonical domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomainname\.eu [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomainname.nl/eu/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```